# why Interface methods will take object as parameter

Tags: java, android

let me take a interface in Android-
**OnClickListener**   and it's method is setonClickListener(), it takes object of
View.OnClickListener or it takes as `this`

why it is taking parameters--that object or `this`

Comment: It takes anything implementing the correct interface, which might be the current class.

Answer (score 1):

The listener object which implements the event call back method.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a listener on the view using [setOnClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29). This listener will be called by android when the view is clicked. The listener can be any object implementing the OnClickListener interface.

And the method called by android on the listener will be [onClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick%28android.view.View%29). And android will pass the view which has been clicked to the method, so that the listener knows which view has been clicked. This allows using the same listener for several views.